# Date format in C

Tags: c

I am trying to change a date entered in the dd/mm/yyyy format to the Month day, year format and I've got it done for the most part but my output adds an extra weird character after the day. This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    char userDate[11];
    char dateWord[11];
    char day[2];
    char year[4];
    printf("Welcome to the Date Formatter.\nPlease input a date in the form of mm/dd/yyyy.\n");
    scanf("%s", userDate);

    day[0] = userDate[3];
    day[1] = userDate[4];
    year[0] = userDate[6];
    year[1] = userDate[7];
    year[2] = userDate[8];
    year[3] = userDate[9];

    if (userDate[0] == '0' && userDate[1] == '1')
        strcpy(dateWord, "January");
    if (userDate[0] == '0' && userDate[1] == '2')
        strcpy(dateWord, "February");
    if (userDate[0] == '0' && userDate[1] == '3')
        strcpy(dateWord, "March");
    if (userDate[0] == '0' && userDate[1] == '4')
        strcpy(dateWord, "April");
    if (userDate[0] == '0' && userDate[1] == '5')
        strcpy(dateWord, "May");
    if (userDate[0] == '0' && userDate[1] == '6')
        strcpy(dateWord, "June");
    if (userDate[0] == '0' && userDate[1] == '7')
        strcpy(dateWord, "July");
    if (userDate[0] == '0' && userDate[1] == '8')
        strcpy(dateWord, "August");
    if (userDate[0] == '0' && userDate[1] == '9')
        strcpy(dateWord, "September");
    if (userDate[0] == '1' && userDate[1] == '0')
        strcpy(dateWord, "October");
    if (userDate[0] == '1' && userDate[1] == '1')
        strcpy(dateWord, "November");
    if (userDate[0] == '1' && userDate[1] == '2')
        strcpy(dateWord, "December");


    printf("The date is:\n");
    printf("%s %s, %s\n", dateWord, day, year);
}
```

And the output is

```
c:\CompSci\C Programming>dateconvert
Welcome to the Date Formatter.
Please input a date in the form of mm/dd/yyyy.
01/23/1998
The date is:
January 23╢ , 1998
```

I'm not sure why the ╢ is being printed.

Comment: `char day[2];` -> `char day[3];` then `day[2] = '\0'`. Otherwise you don't have a valid string in `day`. Same problem for `year`.

Comment: Wow I feel goofy for that one.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Get used to that feeling -- it won't be the last time `:)`

Comment: Note that you've not left any margin for error.  If the user types a space somewhere, you'll get bogus input.  It's generally better to leave room for user's to be inventive and to check that they weren't.  (So, `char userDate[11];` in conjunction with `scanf("%s", userDate);` instead of `scanf("%10s", userDate);` is playing with fire — you will get burned.  You don't check that you get any input — you should.

Answer (score 7):

There's already functions for date parsing and formatting, `strptime` and `strftime`. So you can use them. First, use `strptime` to parse the date into a `struct tm`.

```
#include <time.h>

struct tm date;
strptime( userDate, "%m/%d/%Y", &date );
```

The date is now in a `struct tm` and from there you can manipulate it with the normal date functions including `strftime` for formatting.

```
char formatted_date[40];
strftime( formatted_date, 40, "%B %d, %Y", &date );
puts( formatted_date );
```

One of the benefits of using `strftime` is it will honor the user's locale and provide the month in the appropriate language. C won't honor locales by default, you have to call `setlocale (LC_ALL, "");` from [locale.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_localization_functions).

```
$ ./test
Welcome to the Date Formatter.
Please input a date in the form of mm/dd/yyyy.
01/02/1999
January 02, 1999

$ LC_ALL=es_ES ./test
Welcome to the Date Formatter.
Please input a date in the form of mm/dd/yyyy.
01/02/1999
enero 02, 1999
```

---

Note that your `scanf` should be limited to the size of the userDate buffer else it can overrun the buffer. `%s` should *always* have a limit.

```
scanf("%10s", userDate);
```

And that while some compilers will accept `void main`, it is non-standard. It should always be `int main`.